# Exactly when to user inner join or an alternative query

Tags: sql, inner-join, oracle12c

```
SELECT .... FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2, TABLE3 T3
WHERE T1.NAME = 'ABC' AND T1.ID = T2.COL_ID AND T2.COL1 = T3.COL2
```

vs

```
SELECT .... FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.NAME = 'ABC'
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.COL_ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON  T2.COL1 = T3.COL2
```

Two questions

1. In terms of performance, which will perform better and why?
2. If Option 2 has the better performance, when should be using Option 1?  (vice versa question if Option 1 has better performance)

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: If you want to know which performs better, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) - you've got the query and the data.

Answer (score 1):

The second query is not correct. It should be:

```
SELECT .... FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.COL_ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON  T2.COL1 = T3.COL2
WHERE T1.NAME = 'ABC'
```

This is the right way to write your join condition. The 1st one is accepted, but technically creates a cartesian product. All modern database deals perfectly with both 1st and 2nd queries and interprets them the same way, therefore, performance should be the same. But still, you should use the second one because it is more readable and allows you to have only one way to write join weither it is a inner, left or full outer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy: Don't use comma-separated joins (first query). We used these in the 1980s for the lack of something better, but then in 1992 the new syntax (second query) was introduced<sup>1</sup>, because the old syntax was error-prone (it was easier to forget to apply join criteria) and harder to maintain (was missing join criteria intended or not in a query?) and there was no standard syntax for outer joins.

<sup>1 Oracle was a little late though featuring the new syntax. They introduced the new ANSI joins in Oracle 9i in 2001.</sup>

In terms of performance: There should be no difference in speed, because DBMS optimizers see that this is essentially the same query.

Your second query is syntactically incorrect by the way. The query's `WHERE` clause belongs after the complete `FROM` clause, i.e. after all the joins:

```
SELECT .... 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.col_id 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.col1 = t3.col2
WHERE t1.name = 'ABC';
```